# XPath to select url and email separately

Tags: html, email, url, xpath

I am trying to uniquely select the email address and website url and name, in the following example:

```
<tr>
      <td><a href="http://www.blahblah.com/">blahblah</a></td>
      <td>email: <a href="mailto:info@blahblah.com">info@blahblah.com</a></td>
</tr>
```

This is what I have so far:

Get the email address (this works):

```
//tr/td/a[starts-with(@href, 'mailto')]/text()
```

Get the website link text:

```
//tr/td/a/text()
```

Get the website link url:

```
//tr/td/a@href
```

The problem with the last two XPaths, is that they will return both the website name and url, as well as the email name and url.

Can someone help me find the piece to this puzzle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//tr/td/a[not(starts-with(@href, 'mailto'))]/text()
```

Comment: brilliant! If what I want is not what I know, then just "not" what I know to get what I want. :)
I'd plus you, but the website won't let me :(

Comment: @RobW You can't because of your reputation - but you should accept this answer if it solved your problem. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, Mathias. Still very new to this.